# How to send array of object with form URL encoded through Retrofit Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I want to send form URL encoded to server, but the param need array of object

I have tried use FieldMap from Retrofit and pass the data, but i got different response when I tried with Postman

Param need to pass

```
{
  "allowedStatus": "submit",
  "filters": [
    {
      "userId": "2"
    }
  ],
  "page": 1,
  "pageSize": 2
}
```

Retrofit

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("ticket/status-list")
    fun getTicketStatusList(
        @Field("allowedStatus") allowedStatus: String,
        @FieldMap filters: HashMap<String, String>,
        @Field("page") page: Int,
        @Field("pageSize") pageSize: Int
    ): Observable<Response<TicketListModel>>
```

HashMap

```
val filters = HashMap<String, String>()
        filters["userId"] = "1"
        Log.e("fieldMap", filters.toString())
        getTicketStatusList("monitoring", filters, 1, 5)
```

Result I got {}, response is 200

Comment: Would the filters array have different objects in it or the same one?

Answer (score 1):

Try below way :

```
data class Filters(var userId: String = "")

data class MyRequest(

        var allowedStatus: String = "",
        var filters: ArrayList<Filters>? = null,
        var page: Int = 0,
        var pageSize: Int = 0

        )

@POST("ticket/status-list")
fun getTicketStatusList(@Body request: MyRequest): Observable<Response<TicketListModel>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this:

```
val filters = HashMap<String, RequestBody>()
filters.put("userId", toRequestBody("2"))
getTicketStatusList("monitoring", filters, 1, 5)
```

Also change hashmap of "String" into "RequestBody"

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("ticket/status-list")
    fun getTicketStatusList(
        @Field("allowedStatus") allowedStatus: String,
        @FieldMap filters: HashMap<String, RequestBody>,
        @Field("page") page: Int,
        @Field("pageSize") pageSize: Int
    ): Observable<Response<TicketListModel>>
```

Below method converts String to RequestBody

```
fun toRequestBody(value: String): RequestBody {
        return RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), value)
}
```

Comment: please try also "@FieldMap(encoded = true) filters: HashMap<String, RequestBody>,"

Comment: still same response

Comment: first try to change  "Observable<Response<TicketListModel>>" into "Observable<TicketListModel>" and if it doesn't work then try to use map instead of hashmap like "@FieldMap(encoded = true) filters: Map<String, RequestBody>,"